# LightSwitch - "Reference properties cannot be set to deleted or discarded entities."

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am experiencing this exception when trying to define a data member contained within another piece of data.

Example:

```
Container newRecord = this.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.Containers.AddNew();
newRecord.SubContainer = this.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.SubContainers.AddNew();
```

The exception, `"Reference properties cannot be set to deleted or discarded entities."`, is encountered with the second line.

I don't understand what entity it's talking about with regard to it being discarded or deleted, so any help with this issue would be most appreciated.

The code lines are in an interface function defined in LightSwitch, which is called from a Silverlight project, passing data from that project to the LightSwitch project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually managed to do this after working out that I needed to be on the 'Logic' thread, which I was not.  I spent a little while messing around trying to find a `this.DataContext` but could not (my Silverlight project had this but not the LightSwitch project).

Eventually though I found out what I needed to do:

```
this.Details.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
Container newRecord = this.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.Containers.AddNew();
newRecord.SubContainer = this.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.SubContainers.AddNew();
newRecord.exampleIntProperty=2;
newRecord.SubContainer.innerString="Example";
});
```

I can then assign data to the properties of `newRecord` and the properties of the objects it contains (such as the example `SubContainer`'s properties), although obviously the new record is not saved until LightSwitch is instructed to save its data.

Comment: While that method *will* sort of work (as in it compiles), that's not the way to do it. You shouldn't be creating your SubContainer child entity using the DataWorkspace, you should be calling it from the parent entity's child collection. Then the relationship between them is set automatically. See my comment in my other reply.

Comment: It doesn't just compile, it also appears to work exactly as I wanted it to, allowing me to add data to the record accordingly.  I have not noticed any issues.

Comment: Actually, my apologies, the scenario that I was describing had the relationship the other way around. If your Container entity only has a single SubContainer, you're right, the navigation collection that I was talking about will be on the child entity, not the parent entity. I had the wrong thing in my head. I was thinking that a Container could have many SubContainers, not just the one. I was so sure that I was right, that's why I was so insistent, but I was talking about what I *thought* you had said, not what you *actually* said, so I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to be changed slightly:

```
Container newRecord = this.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.Containers.AddNew();
SubContainer newSub = newRecord.SubContainers.AddNew();
```

If the navigation property isn't called *SubContainers*, just replace that with the correct name.

Comment: Unfortunately I can only see the properties of `SubContainer` with no `AddNew()` function.  The only functions I can see are `Delete()`, `Equals()`, `GetHashCode()`, `GetType()` and `ToString().`

This may be because there is no plural `SubContainers` property for `Containers`?

Comment: When you added the parent/child relationship between the two tables, what name did you call the child navigation property. The parent entity will get a navigation collection property, & the child will get an entity navigation property. The AddNew in my suggestion is a method of the SubContainers navigation collection property (or whatever that's called), not a method of the SubContainer property. You can only AddNew from a collection, not a single entity. Does that make sense now?

Comment: I understand what you're saying.  There is a `SubContainer` in a `Container` because there is a relationship between the two.  There are no accessible collections that I can see in the Container properties via `newRecord.XXXX`